# javascript change anchor tag title value from PHP Echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a class assigned to an anchor tag called status_button. On click of the image associated with the anchor tag it runs the attached function. Two variables are passed to a php script and a 3 piece data response is echo'ed back separated by semicolon's.  I have set up alerts to ensure the correct data is coming back from php.

The thing I need help with is how to change the anchor tag title value using the echo'ed response. There are 5 examples out of probably 20 that I have tried. None of them work, but I get no error's either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".status_button").on('click', function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var I = element.attr("id");
    var id = $("#id" + I).val();
    var sname = $(this).attr("title");
    $.post("openclose.php", {
        id: id,
        sname: sname
    },      
    function (data) {
        var response = (data).split(";", 3);
        alert(response[0]);
        alert(response[1]);
        alert(response[2]);

        $("#messageA" + I).innerhtml = (response[0]);
        $("#messageA" + I).hide();
        $("#messageA" + I).fadeIn(1500);
        $("#messageB" + I).html(response[1]);
        $("#messageB" + I).hide();
        $("#messageB" + I).fadeIn(1500);

        ***$(this).attr("title",(response[2]));
        ***$(I).attr("title", (response[2]));
        ***$("#id" + I).attr("title" , (response[2]));
        ***document.getElementById(I).title = (response[2]);
        ***document.getElementById("#id" +I).setAttribute("title",(response[2]));
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The title of the anchor, or the text of the anchor?

Comment: title - from <a id="1" title ="O1" to <a id="1" title ="C1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... I had to change a few things around to get this to work the way I needed it to. First off I removed the title from my anchor tag and placed it in my div tag. I then reduced my response from my php file from 3 down to 2 pieces of data.

```
$(".status_button").on('click', function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var I = element.attr("id");
    var id = $("#id" + I).val();
    var xname = $("#messageA" + I).attr('title');
    $.post("openclose.php", {
        id: id,
        xname: xname
    },      
    function (data) {
    var response = (data).split(";", 2);
        $("#messageA" + I).attr('title', (response[0]));        
        $("#messageB" + I).html(response[1]);
        $("#messageB" + I).hide();
        $("#messageB" + I).fadeIn(1500);

    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$("#1").attr("title", (response[2]));
```

Your attempts:

```
    ***$(this).attr("title",(response[2])); //this is no longer referring to the clicked element when inside the callback
    ***$(I).attr("title", (response[2])); //Missing # for ID
    ***$("#id" + I).attr("title" , (response[2])); //Not your element ID
    ***document.getElementById("#id" +I).setAttribute("title",(response[2])); //Not your ID
```

Comment: Hey tymeJV thanks for the response back, but the title did not change when I ran it.  Thanks, Kurt

Comment: Run a `console.log($("#" + I).attr("title"));` -- does it produce your title?

Comment: returns a Y1 when I run it

Comment: so make sure I am doing this correct...I took console.log($("#" + I).attr("title")); and placed it in my javascript, ran it and viewed Y1 in my console log in chrome. Y1 is not the title value....would either be O1 or C1.  Thanks,  Kurt

Comment: tymeJV...no dice.  Didn't change. Thanks, Kurt

Comment: A quick update I ran this console.log(document.getElementById(I).title = (response[2])); and it returned the correct value in the log, but did not actually change it.  Thanks, Kurt